# FInd range of in-betweeen nodes

Tags: javascript, html, range, dom-manipulation

Suppose we have a htmlblock like `<p><a>abc</a>[]<br></p>`and now we drag and drop a node at the position of the square brackets.
In my current range I have 'abc' as the container and 2 as the offset this makes the dropped node to get inserted inside the anchor node.

```
<p><a>abc<span>DraggedNode</span></a><br></p>
```

Is there some way that once the at the start or end of the node we range at p and offest as the position we have our cursor.

```
<p><a>abc</a><span>DraggedNode</span><br></p>
```

I figured out how can we find we the cursor is at the start or the end using range, offset and length of the text node. But unable to set selection at the required posititon.